# cut&paste replace in openxml

Tags: c#, openxml

Is there way in DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing to replicate functionality of cut&paste in real Word? Selection to cut&paste may start in the middle of text, include few paragraphs or/and tables and end in the middle of another run.

Comment: Check whether DocumentBuilder works for you   http://ericwhite.com/blog/documentbuilder-expanded/

Comment: DocumentBuilder is great tool and I use it a lot. However, it works (in my understanding) with at least Paragraph. I struggle with necessity to start in the middle of the paragraph, use few consequential ones and finish in the middle of another paragraph. And I can't break Paragraph to deal with 2 paragraphs. It should be smooth run - just like real Word does.